# Android app hangs on getting post preview

Tags: bug, android-app

I've just tried to post a report about imposibility to see the inbox messages via Android app, but actually I'm unable to do more actions. In partucular:

- load an inbox page
- upload an image to the post
- get preview for the post

In the last case I'm actually unable to discard this endless operation.

> [image: app]

Current bug has been posted via web site.

Comment: *Android app is malfunction* is an awesome title had this been yet another rant about the app. Reading the body of your question there seems to be a specific issue with a feature of the app. Can you make your title a bit less broad, if not less ranty?

Comment: android app is long time "malfunctioning" since the team spend 0 time on this, hence it ought to die at some point. To be honest, I'm amazed people still use it. :)

Comment: I use it cause it is the only way to get notifications on mobile

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm amazed people still use ... Android :)

Comment: @rene feel free to edit the title.

Comment: I see @πάντα took the honors ...

Comment: @rene Well, if OP's get too lazy for such things :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wouldn't call it that, writing a good title can be hard.

Comment: @rene Was biddie easy in this case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can the "hang" be live? I mean can we say "app hangs" when progress indicator looks active.

Comment: @alexolut Well, if it doesn't end that "active state" within a reasonable time?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yep. But "reasonable time" may also fails on tooooo slow connection I think.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well, using it too for this same reason and at most I sometimes write some reply comments via the app, but that's about it. I never posted a question or answer via the app (maybe except one time to get a hat few years ago), and don't expect the app to actually work.